# Convert datetime column values to MonYY format

Tags: sql-server

I want to convert datetime to `monYY` format:

Like as below:

```
Jan20
Feb20
Mar20
Apr20
```

Can someone help to write this logic?

Comment: What version of sql server?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @Date DATE= '2020-01-20'
SELECT REPLACE(RIGHT(CONVERT(VARCHAR(9), @Date, 6), 6), ' ', '') AS MonYY
```

If you are using `SQL Sever 2012`, You can do this

```
SELECT FORMAT(@Date, 'MMMyy') as MonYY
```

**Output**

[image]